# Setting the response status code in Sightly

Tags: sling, sightly

I have a Sightly template which I want to use as an Apache Sling error handler.

How do I set the status code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`response` is a global object for Use-API objects. In Java you can access these objects from the bindings map, whereas in the JavaScript implementation of the Use-API these global objects are in the global namespace.

Java Use-API example:

```
public class ErrorHandlerUseObject implements Use {

    @Override
    public void init(Bindings bindings) {
        SlingHttpServletResponse response = (SlingHttpServletResponse) bindings.get(SlingBindings.RESPONSE);
        response.setStatus(403);
    }
}
```

JavaScript Use-API example (let's assume the script's name is `errorhandler.js`):

```
use(function () {
    response.setStatus(403);
});
```

In your Sightly template instantiating any of the defined Use objects should do the trick of setting your response code:

```
<html data-sly-use.errorHandler="ErrorHandlerUseObject">
...
</html>

<html data-sly-use.errorHandler="errorhandler.js">
...
</html>
```